# General purpose diode between 2 power rails

Tags: power, diodes, dc

I am looking at a schematic where there is a general purpose diode connected between the positive side of a 5V DC rail to the positive side of a 12 V DC rail.

The circuit is powered by a power supply that provides 12 & 5 V DC and these two input voltages are connected to a choke. The other side of the choke is where the diode connects the 5V to the 12V rail as seen in the picture.

What's the function of this diode?

[image]

Comment: Describe what happens if the 5 V supply comes up, but the 12 V supply fails?

Comment: Impossible to answer completely without more context. If the supply voltages are at their nominal voltages, then the diode is reverse-biased; so it's probably protecting "something else" or else it is related to power-supply sequencing. Can you edit the question to show more context?

Answer (score 4):

It is there to protect IC's that require the 12V at all times that the 5V is present (possibly older memory ICs). If the 12V drops faster than the 5V supply on power down, you could have 5V still when the 12V bias is gone. This insures that if the 12V drops faster, it will not 'over-run' the 5V as they approach 0V. Some chips can be destroyed if the 12V is not turned on first or simultaneously with the 5V, and at power down, the 12V must stay above the 5V supply at all times. I assume the difference due to the .7V diode loss will not hurt the ICs.

Answer (score 1):

there's probably a part in there there that will be broken if the 12V input is significantly less than the 5V input. the diode prevents this.